# Programmatically creating new order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having the hardest time programmatically creating an order in WooCommerce. I am using the code below and is DOES create an order BUT I cannot get customer information OR product line items added to the order. The new order that is create is simply as Guest with no items, user information, etc.

The issue seems to be that once the order object is created, it is failing when trying to add data to the order.

```
function create_vip_order() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $address = array(
      'first_name' => '111Joe',
      'last_name'  => 'Conlin',
      'company'    => 'Speed Society',
      'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
      'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
      'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
      'address_2'  => '104',
      'city'       => 'San Diego',
      'state'      => 'Ca',
      'postcode'   => '92121',
      'country'    => 'US'
  );

  // Now we create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();

  // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
  $order->add_product( get_product( '275962' ), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
  $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
  //
  $order->calculate_totals();
  $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'create_vip_order' );
```

Here is the error I am getting in my logs:

```
[19-Apr-2016 21:16:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_product() on boolean in /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/themes/ss/lib/contests/order.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): create_vip_order('')
#1 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php(330): do_action('woocommerce_ini...')
#2 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): WooCommerce->init('')
#3 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-settings.php(392): do_action('init')
#4 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-config.php(67): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#5 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#6 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#7 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-admin/edit.php(10): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/themes/ss/lib/contests/order.php on line 107
```

Any help on this would be MOST appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing the add_product function we can only guess but it is likely to be the problem.

Comment: It is a function of WooCommerce and I have now included the full path to this function in the code. After researching this,  it seemed very common on most examples I found to use $order->add_product, $order->set_address, etc. If there is another way I should be doing this, please let me know.

Comment: the function seems to be returning false when $product or $item_id don't exist. You may want to look into whether you're passing valid variables. When working with objects it's advised to run your code in try/catch blocks so they may catch the errors although I am unfamiliar with how much error handling the woocommerce classes have.

Comment: try it on `woocommerce_loaded`... because `wc_create_order` requires `woocommerce_init`...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is in your action hook. Use following hook :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'create_vip_order');

function create_vip_order() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $address = array(
      'first_name' => '111Joe',
      'last_name'  => 'Conlin',
      'company'    => 'Speed Society',
      'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
      'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
      'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
      'address_2'  => '104',
      'city'       => 'San Diego',
      'state'      => 'Ca',
      'postcode'   => '92121',
      'country'    => 'US'
  );

  // Now we create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();

  // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
  $order->add_product( get_product('275962'), 1); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
  $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
  //
  $order->calculate_totals();
  $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);  
}
```

Make sure the product id given should exists in the system.

Comment: Prolem was in hooking into woocommerce_init which several people pointed out but I awarded you the bounty for the first one to supply a complete "answer". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy that my answer helped you. Thanks. :)

Comment: Should be using "wc_get_product" instead of "get_product" now

Answer (score 11):

Well you can do this without wc_create_order function.

```
            $order_data                        = array();
            $order_data[ 'post_type' ]         = 'shop_order';
            $order_data[ 'post_status' ]       = 'wc-' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_order_status', 'pending' );
            $order_data[ 'ping_status' ]       = 'closed';
            $order_data[ 'post_author' ]       = 1;
            $order_data[ 'post_password' ]     = uniqid( 'order_' );
            $order_data[ 'post_title' ]        = sprintf( __( 'Order &ndash; %s', 'woocommerce' ), strftime( _x( '%b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p', 'Order date parsed by strftime', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $post_date ) ) );
            $order_data[ 'post_parent' ]       = 12; // parent post id
            $order_data[ 'post_content' ]      = "";
            $order_data[ 'comment_status' ]    = "open";
            $order_data[ 'post_name' ]         = sanitize_title( sprintf( __( 'Order &ndash; %s', 'woocommerce' ), strftime( _x( '%b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p', 'Order date parsed by strftime', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $post_date) ) ) );

            $order_id = wp_insert_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_order_data', $order_data ), true );
```

Then you can use this $order_id for adding other details, like...

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$product_item_id = $order->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ));
wc_add_order_item_meta($product_item_id,"meta_key","meta_values");
$addressShipping = array(
       'first_name' => $shippingName,
       'email'      => $user_email_id,
       'phone'      => $billingPhone,
       'address_1'  => $shippingAddress,
       'address_2'  => $shippingAddress2,
       'city'       => $shippingCity,
       'state'      => $shippingStateCode,
       'postcode'   => $shippingZip,
       'country'    => 'US');
$order->set_address( $addressShipping, 'shipping' );
    $addressBilling = array(
       'first_name' => $billingName,
       'email'      => $user_email_id,
       'phone'      => $billingPhone,
       'address_1'  => $billingAddress,
       'address_2'  => $billingAddress2,
       'city'       => $billingCity,
       'state'      => $billingStateCode,
       'postcode'   => $billingZip,
       'country'    => 'US');
$order->set_address( $addressBilling, 'billing' );
$order->calculate_totals();
```

Comment: for doing it without wc APIs

Comment: I have a custom form, I want to create an order according to form items, I have hook after the form saved, how can I redirect the cutomer to check out page after this custom order created?

Answer (score 6):

I actually couldn't figure out your problem but providing you another alternative, this might help you.

I have added products in `$woocommerce->cart` first and then assign that cart data to new order created like this :

//For simple product

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
```

//For variable product

```
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variationID, $attr_array);

    $order_data = array(
         'status' => apply_filters('woocommerce_default_order_status', 'processing'),
         'customer_id' => $user_id
    );
    $new_order = wc_create_order($order_data);
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
            $item_id = $new_order->add_product(
                    $values['data'], $values['quantity'], array(
                'variation' => $values['variation'],
                'totals' => array(
                    'subtotal' => $values['line_subtotal'],
                    'subtotal_tax' => $values['line_subtotal_tax'],
                    'total' => $values['line_total'],
                    'tax' => $values['line_tax'],
                    'tax_data' => $values['line_tax_data'] // Since 2.2
                )
                    )
            );
        }
    $new_order->set_address($address, 'billing');
    $new_order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
```

Comment: @Maha..I tried this code although still get member function errors. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_to_cart() on null in /Users/joe...`

Comment: Did you declare `$woocommerce` global with my code?

Comment: Yes, declared $woocommerce and still get the error. Tried this on a fresh build as well with the same result so still ahve an issue in the code I'm using.

Comment: Ofcorse `woocommerce_init` will incur this problem because woocommerce components are not loaded yet properly. You need to change you hook for that.

Comment: @MahaDev I have this same issue but I'm not sure what you mean by change the hook. I assume, you mean add a function that will get the missing init variables and return them, but I'm not quite sure what this looks like. I have `$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();` and I am getting the `call to member function get_checkout_url() on null` message... my call is coming directly after I create an order using wc_create_order()... so I'm guessing I have to add the order programmatically to the cart first or I have to init something else... thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

you almost had it, `add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'create_vip_order' );`
woocommerce_init is too early, you need to change your hook to at least init, 
your errors

```
[19-Apr-2016 21:16:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_product() on boolean in /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/themes/ss/lib/contests/order.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): create_vip_order('')
#1 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php(330): do_action('woocommerce_ini...')
#2 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): WooCommerce->init('')
#3 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-settings.php(392): do_action('init')
#4 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-config.php(67): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#5 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#6 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#7 /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-admin/edit.php(10): require_once('/Users/joe/Site...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /Users/joe/Sites/speedsociety-2/wp-content/themes/ss/lib/contests/order.php on line 107
```

show that it's happening the $order variable has been returned false and hence you can't use `$order->add_product`

here's my working code

```
function create_vip_order() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $address = array(
      'first_name' => '111Joe',
      'last_name'  => 'Conlin',
      'company'    => 'Speed Society',
      'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
      'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
      'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
      'address_2'  => '104',
      'city'       => 'San Diego',
      'state'      => 'Ca',
      'postcode'   => '92121',
      'country'    => 'US'
  );

  // Now we create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();

  // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
  $order->add_product( get_product( '129' ), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
  $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
  //
  $order->calculate_totals();
  $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_vip_order' );
```

Good luck and happy coding :D

Comment: You are correct but had to award the bounty to @maha as he answered first but wanted to say thanks for the answer.