# Cannot create order Woocommerce rest Api php

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried the following code and tried to post values from android to place an order but every time i test it on chrome it give http 500 error, and Android gives volly server error. Dont know where i am messing up, serious help would be appriciated. Thank You
Ask me if you need to take a look at the android Code, but i think that doesnot matter here because i am giving hard coded values in $data.

```
<?php

require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

$pageNum=1;
$pageNum=$_GET['page_num'];

$options = array(
'debug'           => true,
'return_as_array' => false,
'validate_url'    => false,
'timeout'         => 30,
'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

try {

$client = new WC_API_Client( 'https://www.move2mart.com/', 'ck_0afa3a49305683160fe34189553a660053bd4e6239', 'cs_7dc38a7b52c3fdd34qw61e34090be636ae3364b196', $options );

//$data=array();
$data=[
'payment_method' => 'cod',
'payment_method_title' => 'Cash on Delivery',
'set_paid' => false,
'billing' => [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'address_1' => '969 Market',
    'city' => 'Karachi',
    'email' => 'princeali@testing.com',
    'phone' => '03123121995'
], 'line_items' => [

    [
        'product_id' => 779,
        'quantity' => 1
    ]
]
];  

print_r($client->post('orders', $data));

if($_POST !=null) {
}

else{
  echo "Null POST Request";
}   
} catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

   echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
   echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

   if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {
      print_r( $e->get_request() );
      print_r( $e->get_response() );
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729701/programmatically-creating-new-order-in-woocommerce/36929630#36929630

Comment: @MahaDev i am using Woocommerce REST API, am not coding directly in functions.php or the website itself.

Comment: @MahaDev i followed this https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-properties

Comment: @MahaDev tried still getting null at "billing_address":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"","email":"","phone":""}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$orderData = array(    
    "order" => array(
        "billing_address" => array(
            array(
                "first_name" => "",
                "last_name" => "",
                "company" => "",
                "address_1" => "",
                "address_2" => "",
                "city" => "",
                "state" => "",
                "postcode" => "",
                "country" => "",
                "email" => "",
                "phone" => "",
            )
        ),
        "shipping_address" => array(
            array(
                "first_name" => "",
                "last_name" => "",
                "company" => "",
                "address_1" => "",
                "address_2" => "",
                "city" => "",
                "state" => "",
                "postcode" => "",
                "country" => "",
            )
        ),
        "customer_id" => 1,
        "line_items" => array( 
            array(
                "product_id" => 1, 
                "quantity" => 1
            ) 
        )
    )
);

$client->orders->create($orderData);
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: ok just found an other issue, fileds are not properly getting mapped like if i put 'first_name' => 'John' it wont map it to orders, but it does create and  order with a blank name.

Comment: Sir you think you can also help me with that?

Comment: tried still getting null at "billing_address":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":‌​"","address_1":"","a‌​ddress_2":"","city":‌​"","state":"","postc‌​ode":"","country":""‌​,"email":"","phone":‌​""}

Comment: The only thing which is fine is line_items, products are the only thing showing up in order.

Comment: yes, php won't compile with out the comma separator, i retried it with your latest edit, still no luck.

Comment: @PrinceAli have you pass value on above mention field? ex: `first_name, lastname` etc...

Comment: Yes I did. I tested it through hardcoding values as well as getting from $_POST['name'] none worked

Comment: Snaps are here: (1) http://prntscr.com/f0k3ae (2) http://prntscr.com/f0k3h7

Comment: @PrinceAli I apologise my answer, `billing_address` and `shipping_address` write in `order` array. I have updated my answer. Would you please check it?

Comment: Still getting null.

Comment: **Snaps** (1) http://prntscr.com/f0mrn0   (2) http://prntscr.com/f0msfr

Comment: ok i fixed is structured it according to the json null responce. Thank You so much for your cooperation. (Thumbs Up)

Comment: @PurvikDhorajiya I am new here. I don't know more about how to place an order by using the REST API inside a native mobile application. I have tried this `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY&consumer_secret=SECRET_KEY` Rest API for orders. But not understand how to get user cart product information, billing, and shipping information inside that POST API. So can you please help me here and also inform me where I need to do add your above-mentioned code inside my WooCommerce based website.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured it out after some research. Below is working code of woocommerce checkout webservice that may Help you -

```
 /*** Just Copy & Paste and change your varriables **/

    //do your initial stuff 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $json_file=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonvalue= json_decode($json_file,true);

     $user_id = $jsonvalue['user_id']; 
     $product_id = $jsonvalue['product_id']; 
     $quantity = $jsonvalue['quantity'];    

 //start order data 
 $orderData = array(    
     "order" => array(
     'payment_method' => 'paypal',
     'payment_method_title' => 'Paypal',
     'set_paid' => true,
    "billing_address" => array(
                                    "first_name" => "bfname",
                                    "last_name" => "blname",
                                    "company" => "testcompanybilling",
                                    "address_1" => "sec8",
                                    "address_2" => "e32",
                                    "city" => "noida",
                                    "state" => "Noida",
                                    "postcode" => "99999",
                                    "country" => "IN",
                                    "email" => "test@gmail.com",
                                    "phone" => "888899999999"

                            ),
      "shipping_address" => array(
                                    "first_name" => "sfname",
                                    "last_name" => "slname",
                                    "company" =>  "testcompanyshipping",
                                    "address_1" => "shakkarpur",
                                    "address_2" => "laxminigar",
                                    "city" => "New Delhi",
                                    "state" => "Delhi",
                                    "postcode" => "110092",
                                    "country" => "IN",
                                    "email" => "testsh@gmail.com",
                                    "phone" => "11009999"   
                              ),
    "customer_id" => $user_id,
    "line_items" => array( 
        array(
            "product_id" => $product_id, 
            "quantity" => $quantity
        ) 
      ),
    'shipping_lines' => array(
    array(
        'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
        'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
        'total' => 10
    )
)
   )
);

//Create order usind order data
 $data =  $client->orders->create($orderData);
//echo '<pre>';
 //print_r($data);
$result['success']='true';
$result['error']="0";
$result['msg']='Your order has been successfully placed.';  
$result['data']=$data;  

 echo json_encode($result); `
```

cheers!!!