# How will I create woocommerce order programmatically in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am writing a php json service for mobile app with my Wordpress/Woocommerce site. I have to create an order of bookable hotels which have checkin and checkout date.

How will place an order programmatically using with or with out Woocommerce functions?

Any help is appreciated.

My Hotel room's post type is `hotel_room`. I have to update wp_posts, wp_postmeta, woocommerce tables etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically creating new order in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729701/programmatically-creating-new-order-in-woocommerce)

Comment: @RADEK This is about Woocommerce Rest Api, so it is not a duplicate from the linked thread.