# Button that create an order on WooCommerce for the current product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, form-submit, orders

I am using *"[Programmatically creating new order in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729701/programmatically-creating-new-order-in-woocommerce/36929630#36929630)"* answer code and I want when I clicking button that an order comes to admin panel.

Here is my attempt:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
   switch ($_POST['action']) {

        case 'new_order':
            new_order();
            break;
    }
}

function new_order() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $address = array(
       'first_name' => $shippingName,
       'email'      => $user_email_id,
       'phone'      => $billingPhone,
       'address_1'  => $shippingAddress,
       'address_2'  => $shippingAddress2,
       'city'       => $shippingCity,
       'state'      => $shippingStateCode,
       'postcode'   => $shippingZip,
       'country'    => 'US');
    );

    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product( get_product());
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );  
    $order->calculate_totals();   
    $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);
}
```

And My button:

```
 <input type="submit" id="button" name="new_order" value="Submit" >
```

Is that the correct way? Any Help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated 2** - Your code is a bit outdated as `get_product()` is replaced by `wc_get_product()` since a while.

**1) First the function that is going to create the order** *(with a variable that handle the product Id added to the order)*:

```
function trigger_new_order( $from_product_id ) {
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => "Joe",
        'last_name'  => "Doe",
        'email'      => "john.doe@gmail.com",
        'phone'      => "0123456789",
        'address_1'  => "1 St. James Street",
        'address_2'  => "",
        'city'       => "San Francisco",
        'state'      => "California",
        'postcode'   => "92105",
        'country'    => "US"
    );

    $order = wc_create_order( $from_product_id );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' ); // The Shipping address

    $product    = wc_get_product( $from_product_id );

    $order->add_product( $product );

    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status( 'completed', 'Imported order', true );

    // Display a message with the order number
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __("Order #%d has been created"), $order->get_id() ) . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

---

**2) The form with the submit button that is going to create the order**

In the example below, we use this code on single product pages (on front end) and we get dynamically the product Id:

```
if ( isset($_POST['new-order']) && $_POST['new-order'] === 'Submit' ) {
    trigger_new_order( get_the_id() );
} else {
    ?>
    <form class="new" method="post">
        <input class="button alt" type="submit" id="button" name="new-order" value="Submit" >
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: $from_product_id -  undefinded variable it tels me,
trigger_new_order - method call uses 1 parametres but method signatures uses 0 parametres

Comment: @ElVyganto Sorry a little oversight in my code… updated

Comment: No. That not worked. By the way i trying to put all this to popup.
https://www.part.lt/perziura/867bc1954ee91b23bcedf5f75f734fe8365.png

Comment: @ElVyganto I have tested the code on single product pages and it works (on last WooCommerce version)… The order is generated and visible on backend.