# woocommerce custom order request

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am facing problems with custom order request. Actually I want to show 1 form in anywhere of my website and when any customer fill that form then as a admin I will get approve or disapprove option if I do Approve the customer will be get notified by email but if I approve this will be converted as a Order. also if I reject customer will be get notified How can I do this?

Comment: Why not using custom order status and if you approve change it to what you want ? Check this answer hwo to create order - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729701/programmatically-creating-new-order-in-woocommerce . Create a form and add your $_POST data in it

Comment: I did use  Custom order status but that is applying for all products that I don't want also I don't want to take them cart,checkout etc, Actually I need 1 form there customer can write what product they need (that product not exist on my website) as a admin if I get that information I need approve or reject option . and then I will send to customer  order tracking link.

Comment: Thats what i am saying just create a dummy orders without client data they will be assigned as guest by default. Your form will create those dummy orders. then create your real order. another option is to create custom admin page, create custom post named requested_orders for example. Your form again will create those posts with your data. Create a field in your custom post that is with statuses. You can create your orders from there or just go to orders -> new order and proceed.

Comment: this is my first question here  but I am really grateful to you to get this kind of help. I am trying to follow your method. thanks!!